# Perl Getopt::Long Assigning variable then going to subroutine

Tags: perl, getopt, getopt-long

I have the following piece of code

```
my $use = "Use: " . basename($0) . " [options]";
my $version = "Version: 0.1 \n";
my $variableA;
my $variableB;

GetOptions(
'a=s'           => \$variableA,
'help'          => sub { print $use; exit 0 },
'version'       => sub { print $version; exit 0 },
'b'             => sub { \$variableB, &this_subroutine; goto NOWGOHERE; },
 );

die "Incorrect use. \n" unless (defined $variableA || defined $variableB);

sub this_subroutine {

     print "$variableB\n";

}

NOWGOHERE: print "HELLO I'M NOW HERE\n";
```

What I am trying to do is set `$variableB` and then do the `&this_subroutine` and the `goto NOWGOHERE` but I can only get it to do one or the other, not both, using either `'b=s' => \$variableB,` or `sub { &this_subroutine; goto NOWGOHERE;0 },`

When trying to do both I cannot seem to print the `$variableB`, is there something obvious I am missing or doing wrong syntactically?

Using `'b=s' => \$variableB, sub { &this_subroutine; goto NOWGOHERE; },` does not seem to work either?

your help is much appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$variableB` will never have a value because you never assign to it.

```
'a=s'           => \$variableA,
```

gives `$variableA` a value because, when Getopt::Long is given a scalar ref, it assigns the option's value to that scalar.

On the other hand,

```
'b'             => sub { \$variableB, &this_subroutine; goto NOWGOHERE; },
```

gives Getopt::Long a *code* reference, which it can't assign the option value to.

Based on the docs, it appears that it passes the option name and option value to the coderef as parameters, in which case

```
'b=s'             => sub { $variableB = $_[1]; this_subroutine(); goto NOWGOHERE; },
```

should probably do what you want.

Comment: @DaveSherohman - When using `'b' => sub { $variableB = $_[0]; this_subroutine(); goto NOWGOHERE; },` the $variableB equals `b`, which as you said appears to pass the option name. However when using `'b' => sub { $variableB = $_[1]; this_subroutine(); goto NOWGOHERE; },` the $variableB equals `1`, rather than the argument I supplied at the command line?

Comment: Figured out the reason, it was because `=s` was still required, see the edit, thanks a lot for your help.